# MVC 3 Cant turn off unobtrusive javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I've been implementing the new unobtrusive javascript in my mvc 3 project (using RC1).
I've added the 3 required scripts to a "master" layout page. 
All is working well.

However I have a view where I want to use some normal jquery validation to validate a textbox. To be exact I want to check an entry exists, and that it is numeric.

So on the page my js looks like so...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SomeForm').validate({
        errorClass: "field-validation-error",
        validClass: "field-validation-none",
        errorElement: "label",
        rules: {
            ItemCount: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            ItemCount: {
                required: "Please specify the number of items available",
                number: "Please specify a valid number"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However this was not working. 
So on my master layout page I commented out the reference to the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js file and hey presto it worked.

So I thought, must be something to do with the unobtrusive bits and pieces, so if I turn it off (which I'd read that you can) all will be well.

So, in the view page I added the following line

```
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(false);
```

But no joy. The only way I can get it to work is to remove the reference to the unobtrusive js file.

Surely this can't be the case. I must be being stoppid right?

Thanks D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` already registers a `validate` function on the form which is conflicting with your own. So instead of calling the `validate` function you may try [adding rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

```
$("#myinput").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    messages: {
        required: "Required input",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the new Unobtrusive jQUery Adapter is designed in a way that you either enable it for the whole or none, you cannot conditionally enable/disable it for a specific view.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MVC3 are you on is it CTP, Beta or RC?  It works fine for me in RC using Razor.  Please post the code from the view.

Comment: It is the RC, but Darins has provided the answer. Thanks for looking though.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to web.config and finding this:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

And set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to false. There may be more keys with it though.

Comment: He didn't want to turn it off for everything, just for a specific view.